# WPF Tree View control goes blank if the application is open and idle for long hours

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a tree view in a WPF application made using MVVM architecture.

The tree view code (xaml) is -

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
        <TreeView Name="tvMainNode1" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" BorderThickness="0">

        </TreeView>

</Grid>
```

This tree view is filled up in the xaml.cs like this -

```
public void LoadTree(ObservableCollection<Dictionary<Team, List<AdapterSettings>>> obj)
        {
            LocalTreeViewModel vm = (LocalTreeViewModel)this.DataContext;
            if (tvMainNode1 != null)
            {
                tvMainNode1.Items.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                tvMainNode1 = new TreeView();
            }

.

.

.

.

                            if (treeTeamItem != null)
                            {
                                tvMainNode1.Items.Add(treeTeamItem);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }           
        }
```

Everything works fine. The tree view is loading as required.

But the problem is that whenever the application is open for long time i.e. around 2-3 hours with no user interaction, the tree view goes blank.

I have no idea how.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the mode about the binding? Are you using any timer to load the treeview?

Comment: Your use of calling your View code directly and your supposed usage of MVVM makes me wonder: why do you call that `MVVM`? You should have a `VM` and bind your `V` to it, right?

Comment: @Ganesh The tree view is being loaded when the Load() is called. The method is being called during the navigation flow from one page to another in the OnPageEnter(), BeforePageExit() methods in different ViewModels.

Comment: @nvoigt I know that. The application uses the actual MVVM flow. But this particular part about the tree view is not right. Could you please help in this regard. I am really stuck with this issue.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Without that it is hard to find the problem.

Comment: This isn't mvvm.  And it could absolutely be because of your video card.  WPF is video card sensitive.  Make sure your drivers are updated.  Consider getting a new card if the one you're running is offbrand or suspect.  Also, you can use Snoop to examine the visual tree after the treeview goes blank to see if it is actually empty or if it's just not rendering.